# Javascript not running on site

Tags: javascript, function, iframe

On the following site (http://www.homefresh.co.nz/gallery.html) there is a piece of javascript up the top to dynamically change the height of my iFrame

Javascript in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
function calcHeight()
{
    //find the height of the internal page
    var the_height=document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    //change the height of the iframe
    var the_height = parseFloat(the_height) + 15;
    document.getElementById('the_iframe').height=the_height;
}
//-->
</script>
```

and in the page is the iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.dpdesignz.co.nz/homefresh/" id="the_iframe" onLoad="calcHeight();" height="1" width="920px" scrolling="auto" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

except for some reason it's not updating

I have the exact same code here and it works (http://www.dpdesignz.co.nz/homefresh/test.htm)

Can anyone see anything stopping it?

Comment: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.dpdesignz.co.nz/homefresh/ from frame with URL http://www.homefresh.co.nz/gallery.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
 gallery.html:192
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined  this is what Chrome says when you open the resources tag (after pressing f12

Comment: And Mozilla Firefox says : [11:03:32,838] Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' @ http://www.homefresh.co.nz/gallery.html:192.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page with script and the iframe page have to be on the same domain. This is required by the same [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) because of security matters.

So if you want to access document that's on `www.dpdesignz.co.nz` then you have to use host page that is on `www.dpdesignz.co.nz` domain. That's why one of your scripts works and the other don't.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any work around for this that you know about?

Comment: Nope, no with the iframe.. You can try to download your page through the AJAX request and render in directly on your site, but it will probably just complicate and not really help..

Comment: Thanks for that. Will get back to the drawing board. :)